# how to convert List<dynamic> to List<modal>

Tags: asp.net-core

```
     List<dynamic> _PhysicalResult = new List<dynamic>();
                _PhysicalResult.AddRange(data);
                _PhysicalResult.AddRange(familydata);

 List<ModalReportIndidual1> studentDetails = new List<ModalReportIndidual1>();
studentDetails = _PhysicalResult.ToList();
```

Comment: try studentDetails = _PhysicalResult.Cast<T>();

Comment: what is <T> here ,  i m new to core

Comment: T is your class that you need to convert to, in this case studentdetails

Comment: here studentDetails is local variable for List<ModalReportIndidual1>     List<ModalReportIndidual1> studentDetails = new List<ModalReportIndidual1>();

Comment: If you want to convert list to a new variable,you can try to use `var newList=studentDetails.Cast<modal>();`.

Comment: doesnot work for me

Answer (score 0):

I did an exemplary study. You can change your variables and write this.

```
        var data = new List<dynamic>();
        var familydata = new List<dynamic>();
        
        List<dynamic> _PhysicalResult = new List<dynamic>();
        _PhysicalResult.AddRange(data);
        _PhysicalResult.AddRange(familydata);
        
        List<string> studentDetails = new List<string>();
        
        var i = 0;
        while (i<_PhysicalResult.Count)
        {
            studentDetails.Add(_PhysicalResult[i]);
            i++;
        }
```